# Asynctask hangs on getInputStream()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, java.util.scanner

I've been working at this part of my Android app for hours and I've read at least 50 related posts, but none of them have helped. I have an AsyncTask that attempts to grab text from a website. This should be very simple.

I already have a Java Swing program that calls very similar code that works exactly how I want it to so I know the website and my internet are up and running.

When I try to run the app the AsyncTask hangs at the commented point and I don't know why.

**Stripped version of the AsyncTask innards:**

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.wtf("PROGRESS", "in preex");
    //progress bar
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND + THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);

    try {
        Log.wtf("PROGRESS", "in try");
        URLConnection connection = new URL("https://bmorgan17.github.io/html-database/").openConnection();
        Log.wtf("PROGRESS", "connect");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream()); //HANGS HERE
        Log.wtf("PROGRESS", "got stream");
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        string = scanner.next();
        Log.wtf("PROGRESS", "read");
        scanner.close();
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.wtf("FAILED", "Hard rip mate");
    }

    return string;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    Log.wtf("PROGRESS", "in post");
    //hide progress bar
    delegate.processFinish(s);
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
01-21 13:36:53.039 14480-14480/com.example.name.stemapp A/PROGRESS: in preex
01-21 13:36:53.109 14480-14495/com.example.name.stemapp A/PROGRESS: in try
01-21 13:36:53.125 14480-14495/com.example.name.stemapp A/PROGRESS: connect
```

The progress wheel continues to spin forever after the final logcat entry, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

In the time it took to create this post and 15-20 minutes of Reddit surfing, the app finally moved on. It entered the catch statement and then postExecute which is obviously not what I intend. If anyone could help me solve this new problem it would be great.

**Logcat:**

```
A/PROGRESS: in preex
A/PROGRESS: in try
A/PROGRESS: connect
A/FAILED: hard rip mate
A/PROGRESS: in post
```

Comment: How do you call the AsyncTask?

Comment: What exception occured? What was it's stacktrace?

Comment: Setting a connection timeout would help you debug. `connection.setReadTimeout(5000)` (5 seconds). 

"A SocketTimeoutException can be thrown when reading from the returned input stream if the read timeout expires before data is available for read".

Comment: @ianhanniballake with execute() in the main onCreate() method. I can edit my post if you want

Comment: I get different exceptions every time I run it and none of them occur around the printStackTrace() @Ruku

Answer (score 0):

First, set internet permissions in
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Try this instead:

```
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    String result = "";

    try {

        url = new URL("https://bmorgan17.github.io/html-database");
    //OPEN UP CONNECTION WITH URL
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    //SET UP INPUT STREAM FOR DATA
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    //SET UP READER TO READ THE INCOMING DATA
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    //INPUT STREAM GETS DATA AS CHARACTERS SO THIS READS THE FIRST CHARACTER
        int data = reader.read();
    //LOOP THROUGH EACH CHARACTER UNTIL YOU GET ALL CONTENT REQUESTED
        while (data != -1) {
            char c = (char) data;
     //CONCATANATE TO STRING
            result += c;
            data = reader.read();
        }

        Log.i("Result", result);

        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
             Log.wtf("FAILED", "Hard rip mate");
        }
```

Comment: This is how I understand it. The code always works for me so give it a try.

Comment: it still hangs when it calls getInputStream()

Comment: I updated my response. Try adding that in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
connection.setDoInput(true);
int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
Log.wtf("PROGRESS", "status code: " + statusCode);
```

before

```
Log.wtf("PROGRESS", "connect");
```

EDIT:

Try adding also:

```
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

before:

```
int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

EDIT2:

I just realized your url starts with https and you use HttpUrlConnection. Change it to HttpsUrlConnection.

Comment: Hangs at "int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();"

Comment: I forgot about setting request method, try now please.

Comment: still hangs on getResponseCode()

Comment: One more try, this time with request property too :-) If now it will hang, I give up.

Comment: still hangs at getResponseCode() after adding setRequestProperty()

Comment: I also changed "HttpURLConnection" to Https because the site is Https but it still hangs